# make the div load last using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make my div on my page to load last, what i mean is after everything is loaded then it must load that div using jquery or javascript ?

here is what i tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $.get('url', function(data) {
            $('.image').html(data);
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can also try to use `setTimeout()` method to load your div after a specific time period on your page.

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal setTimeout() doesn't ensure that the callback is executed when everything else is loaded. It simply executes after a specified time no matter what "loading status" other resources might have.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use $(document).ready() because this event fires probably too early for your intention. Use the window.onload event which fires after the page is fully loaded (including images and other resources)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $.get('url', function(data) {
        $('.image').html(data);
   });
};
```